# Allow other pages to access TabNavigator React Native Navigation

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I am using a BottomTabNavigator in my react native/expo project. My navigation structure is very simple, and looks like so:

```
-a
-b
-c
```

where a, b, and c are navigation elements that appear in the BottomTabNavigator. This is essentially the default version.

However I have anther screen 'd', which is accessed from screen 'a' by pressing a different button. There is no way to get to 'd' from the BottomTabNavigator, however I want to be able to get to a, b, and c using the same navigator for d.

Is there a way to make d a 'hidden' element in the tab navigator, or allow it access to the tab navigator without being a direct part of it?

I know a solution with linking a second navigator to b and c, and then having that direct to a or b, however that seems unnecessary and I would prefer not to create another navigator.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correct you want to jump from StackNavigator 'd' to another tab.

```
  CommonActions.reset({
    routes: [
      {
        name: 'a', // could either be 'b' or 'c'
        state: {
          routes: [
            { name: 'a1' },
            {
              name: 'a2',
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
  })
```